# Adding style and javascript to your rail app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys i have created an app which is hosted in my localhost.
No the thing is that i have data from my past rail app
i want to add that entire  source code to my new rail app where there is nothing at the moment what are the steps for me to do that how can i create my style and javascript to the new app

much appreciated guys

Comment: Yes i mean adding the source file of my previous app to the new app

Comment: yes but i can't locate the folder where i have to copy it :$

Comment: The same folders they're in now.

Comment: i did try copying it to the file but its not showing on the home page

Comment: You're not really providing enough information to help diagnose the problem. Edit your question to indicate where you're copying the files too, how you're including them in your templates, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Rails version before 3.1:
CSS and JS files are typically located in `/public/stylesheets/` and `/public/javascripts/`
Copy the files in there to the same location in your new project. Make sure to include them in the `<head>` section of your layout file (typically `/app/views/application.html.erb`)

If you are using a Rails version after 3.1:
CSS and JS files are in `app/assets/javascripts` `app/assets/stylesheets`